# JDBC connection to DB2 for i - only tables of single schema available

Tags: jpa, jdbc, db2, odbc, ibm-midrange

I got this problem, and searched much too long for the solution. It's so simple I can't believe that I got struggled with it.

So to prevent others from waisting time, I will ashamed present the solution.

I'm using EclipsePersistence framework for JPA with the Dali plugin of Eclipse.
My database is a DB2 on an IBM i host (formerly known as AS400 / i5).

No schema of the needed got tables in the list, but they existed.
Only the tables of one single schema could get resolved.

Overriding the default schema in the JPA project dind't work.

Comment: This problem is encountered by people making JDBC or ODBC connections to an IBM i system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was that I specified a default schema in the connection profile itself. So this blocked the tables from other schemas.

The solution is quite simple:

- Open the view `Data Source Explorer`
- Right click on your connection
- Select `Properties`
- On the left select `Driver Propoerties`
- Remove the entry in `Default schema`

Now it works perfectly!

Comment: For readers who are unfamiliar with an IBM i environment, it is generally considered best practice to avoid hard coding schema (aka library) names, but instead to use the "library list" path to let the system resolve references for you.

Comment: Sure, but that will not work if you tend to create an entity from a table... At least not with the Dali plugin, that requires the selection of a schema, instead you don't see anything... Or am I missing something here?